# How can I get all elements in a join table from NSPredicate? (for NSFetchedResultsController)

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Here are my 3 tables

```
House
-userPermissions: [Permission]

Permission
-house: House
-user: User
-permissionLevel: String

User
-housePermissions: [Permission]
```

I want to get all users (regardless of permission level) for a given house.

I want to use an `NSFetchedResultsController` (as I may have 10k users) which means I will have to use an `NSPredicate`.

I've tried the following predicates:

`NSPredicate(format: "SELF IN %@.@user", house.userAccesses ?? [])`

Crash:`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFSet 0x128f3b070> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key user.'`

`NSPredicate(format: "%@.@user", house.userAccesses ?? [])`

Crash: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "%@.@user"'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Users as your result, your fetch request will be on the User entity:

```
let req = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
```

Then, your predicate can be expressed as any user who has any housePermissions on the given house:

```
req.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY housePermissions.house = %@", h1)
```